# Separate php Array from main site

Tags: php, arrays

So, I have a page to display products which I named apple.php :

```
<?php 
    foreach($apple as $item) {
 ?>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 text-xs-center">
                <div class="view third-effect">
                    <a href="<?php echo $item['link'] ?>">
                    <div class="overlay-thing"><i class="fa fa-share" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                    <img src="<?php echo $item['image'] ?>" />
                    </a>
                </div>  
                <p><?php echo $item['name'] ?> </p>
            </div>
 <?php   
 }   
 ?>
```

I use an hardcoded array which looks like this:

```
$apple = array(
 array(
'id' => '1',
'name' => 'iPhone 4',
'link' => 'reparatur/apple/iphone-4.php',
'category' => 'iPhone',
'image' => 'images/iphone4.png'
),

array(
'id' => '2',
'name' => 'iPhone 4s',
'link' => 'reparatur/apple/iphone-4s.php',
'category' => 'iPhone',
'image' => 'images/iphone4s.png'
)
);
```

etc etc...

It has around 10 products.
This array is on top on the file, and I wonder how can I separate this array into an separate file, calling it for example products.php.

How can i then access that array in the file apple.php for the foreach loop.

Also, I will have arrays for samsung, sony products and should I put them all into the same file?

Comment: Keep the array in a different file and include that file ?

Comment: @user3360140 oh god, sometimes my brain has a blockade, yeah, that's is :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php).

i.e. :

**product.php**

```
$apple = array(
    array(
        'id' => '1',
        'name' => 'iPhone 4',
        'link' => 'reparatur/apple/iphone-4.php',
        'category' => 'iPhone',
        'image' => 'images/iphone4.png'
    ),

    array(
        'id' => '2',
        'name' => 'iPhone 4s',
        'link' => 'reparatur/apple/iphone-4s.php',
        'category' => 'iPhone',
        'image' => 'images/iphone4s.png'
    )
);
```

**apple.php**

```
<?php 
    include 'product.php';
    foreach($apple as $item) {
 ?>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 text-xs-center">
                <div class="view third-effect">
                    <a href="<?php echo $item['link'] ?>">
                    <div class="overlay-thing"><i class="fa fa-share" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                    <img src="<?php echo $item['image'] ?>" />
                    </a>
                </div>  
                <p><?php echo $item['name'] ?> </p>
            </div>
 <?php   
 }   
 ?>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file **`apple-products.php`** or any name and add following lines:

```
<?php // apple-list.php

return array(
    array(
        'id' => '1',
        'name' => 'iphone 4',
        'link' => 'reparatur/apple/iphone-4.php',
        'category' => 'iPhone',
        'image' => 'image/iphone4.png',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => '2',
        'name' => 'iphone 4s',
        'link' => 'reparatur/apple/iphone-4s.php',
        'category' => 'iPhone',
        'image' => 'image/iphone4s.png',
    ),
);
```

Now in the top of **`apple.php`** file replace your array with this:

```
$apple = require('apple-products.php'); // assuming apple.php and apple-products.php are in same directory
```

That's it. Hope that helped!